# ellipsizeMode does not work when Text component is wrapped with another Text component

Tags: react-native, text, styles

I'm trying to display a title as given in the picture where it enables user to click 'See more' and expand the text.

[image]

Current implementation:

```
        <Text>
            <Text
                multiline={showFullName}
                numberOfLines={showFullName ? 5 : 2}
                ellipsizeMode="tail"
            >
                {textInputValue}
            </Text>
            <Text
                style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}
                onPress={() => setShowFullName(!showFullName)}
            >
                {showFullName ? 'See less' : 'See more'}
            </Text>
        </Text>
```

In order to get 'See more' text align with the title I have wrapped with an outer Text component. But when wrapped with Text, setting 'ellipsizeMode' to true does not work. Is there a proper way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this. (Check updated answer)

```js
import { Text, View } from 'native-base';

<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text multiline={showFullName} numberOfLines={showFullName ? 5 : 2} ellipsizeMode="middle">
    {textInputValue}
    <View style={{ width: width / 2, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
  </Text>
  <View style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginTop: -16 }}>
    <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>
      {showFullName ? 'See less' : 'See more'}
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Check below image.
[image]

Comment: what does width stands for?

Comment: `import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';`

`const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');`

Import Dimensions and retrieve width.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Goal would be to display much text as possible and add trailing dots at the end. But when adding ellipsizeMode as 'middle' title cuts off in middle.

Comment: If you will add ellipsizeMode as 'middle'  then you will unable to show `see more` button/text after `...` sign then you need to show see more below the line. as I add answer before edit.